# How to Modify An Existing VB.NET Class To Pass Additional Variable

Tags: c#, vb.net, class, oop

My OOP skill is not very strong, I am having a hard time to understand how to modify an existing class to pass additional variables.

**Little bit of background.**

I was trying to print an RDLC report using VB.net. I have found a working C# class and modify it to VB.Net. currently, it's working fine.  The class has a method to assign page height, width and margin value. I have hardcoded it to suit my current need. but I don't want to hardcode it, I want to pass the height, width and margin value to the class.

**Original Class**

[Click To See](https://hastebin.com/oconidaxul.http)

**My Modification Hard Coded In To Class**

```
Return String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>emf</OutputFormat>
                                                            <StartPage>0</StartPage>
                                                            <EndPage>0</EndPage>
                                                            <MarginTop>{0}</MarginTop>
                                                            <MarginLeft>{1}</MarginLeft>
                                                            <MarginRight>{2}</MarginRight>
                                                            <MarginBottom>{3}</MarginBottom>
                                                            <PageHeight>{4}</PageHeight>
                                                            <PageWidth>{5}</PageWidth>
                                                            </DeviceInfo>", ToInches(10),
                                                            ToInches(5), ToInches(5),
                                                            ToInches(10), ToInches(600),
                                                            ToInches(900))
```

**How I Currentely Call It From A Button Click Event**

```
Dim autoprintme As AutoPrintCls = New AutoPrintCls(ReportViewer1.LocalReport)
autoprintme.Print()
```

**How I Want To Call It**

```
Dim hight As Double = 585 
Dim width As Double = 827 
Dim autoprintme As AutoPrintCls = New AutoPrintCls(ReportViewer1.LocalReport, hight, width)
autoprintme.Print()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to pass additional variables to this class *without* breaking what's already existing? No problem, my friend: we'll make a new overload which will call the original one, but with a twist!

Here's the original New() Sub as I read it:

```
    Public Sub New(ByVal report As Report)
        Dim reportPageSettings As ReportPageSettings = report.GetDefaultPageSettings()
        m_pageSettings = New PageSettings()
        m_pageSettings.PaperSize = reportPageSettings.PaperSize
        m_pageSettings.Margins = reportPageSettings.Margins
    End Sub
```

Now, you can add an overload this way (i included the original, untouched code just so it's cristal clear that you don't have to modify it!):

```
    Public Sub New(ByVal report As Report, ByVal height as Double, ByVal width as Double)
        Initialize(report)
        Me.height = height
        Me.width = width
    End Sub

    Private Sub Initialize(ByVal report as Report)
        Dim reportPageSettings As ReportPageSettings = report.GetDefaultPageSettings()
        m_pageSettings = New PageSettings()
        m_pageSettings.PaperSize = reportPageSettings.PaperSize
        m_pageSettings.Margins = reportPageSettings.Margins
        RenderAllLocalReportPages(localReport)
    End Sub
```

Now, I'm sorry because it's late and I'm really assuming things here: I'm assuming that whatever this class is, it's got a width property and a height property. If it's not the case, you'll have to engineer a way to just modify those in a way which makes sense.

You seem to have some coding background so I'm confident that you'll get what I mean, and also good luck! (and if you still have problems don't hesitate to ask about 'em)

Comment: I get the idea. nice way to handle it. Currently, I am out of my workstation, will update in a few hours. Many many thanks.

Comment: @LEON I just modified my answer a little bit. I was kinda tired yesterday and this morning I had a doubt about having a New() calling on a New() - I'm pretty sure it's not a good idea, although I can't get confirmation in a pinch. Si I extracted the initialization part of the original New() in an "Initialize" Sub which both New() will call upon. I think it's much cleaner this way.

Comment: few modifications and its working absolutely fine. Please correct a few things on your code. 1. Change access modifier of initial New Sub to Public. 2. Remove 2nd New Sub, not needed. 3. Change C# reference This to VB reference Me. 4. Add Function Call RenderAllLocalReportPages(localReport) to Initial New Sub. otherwise, it will not work. Your answer is really helpful to me.  Accepting this as an answer. Hope I can tease you with my noob questions in future. :P

Comment: I made those edits. Good job on your understanding! I ha coded this from memory without an IDE so I made a couple mistakes (sorry), and you handled it like a pro! You can question me anytime, I like someone I don't have to hold by the hand the whole way!

Comment: I know you write this without IDE. No pro coders do this kind of mistake with an IDE.  Not only you are a good coder but also a very good person. It's clearly reflecting by your word choice and how you addressing people. It's very rear gift nowadays. Good night from my time zone. :)

Answer (score 0):

You want to pass the height and width as parameters to your CreateEMFDeviceInfo method. It should use those parameters in the string. So..

```
 Private Sub RenderAllLocalReportPages(ByVal localReport As LocalReport)
        Try
            Dim deviceInfo As String = CreateEMFDeviceInfo()
            Dim warnings As Warning()
            localReport.Render("IMAGE", deviceInfo, AddressOf LocalReportCreateStreamCallback, warnings)
        Catch e As Exception
            MessageBox.Show("error :: " & e.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

    Private Function LocalReportCreateStreamCallback(ByVal name As String, ByVal extension As String, ByVal encoding As Encoding, ByVal mimeType As String, ByVal willSeek As Boolean) As Stream
        Dim stream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
        m_pages.Add(stream)
        Return stream
    End Function

    Private Function CreateEMFDeviceInfo() As String
        Dim paperSize As PaperSize = m_pageSettings.PaperSize
        Dim margins As Margins = m_pageSettings.Margins
        Return String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>emf</OutputFormat>
                                                            <StartPage>0</StartPage>
                                                            <EndPage>0</EndPage>
                                                            <MarginTop>{0}</MarginTop>
                                                            <MarginLeft>{1}</MarginLeft>
                                                            <MarginRight>{2}</MarginRight>
                                                            <MarginBottom>{3}</MarginBottom>
                                                            <PageHeight>{4}</PageHeight>
                                                            <PageWidth>{5}</PageWidth>
                                                            </DeviceInfo>", ToInches(margins.Top),
                                                            ToInches(margins.Left), ToInches(margins.Right),
                                                            ToInches(margins.Bottom), ToInches(paperSize.Height),
                                                            ToInches(paperSize.Width))


    End Function
```

becomes

```
     Private Sub RenderAllLocalReportPages(ByVal localReport As LocalReport)
    Try
        Dim pageHeight, pageWidth as Integer
        'Set values
        '....

        Dim deviceInfo As String = CreateEMFDeviceInfo(pageHeight,pageWidth)
        Dim warnings As Warning()
        localReport.Render("IMAGE", deviceInfo, AddressOf LocalReportCreateStreamCallback, warnings)
    Catch e As Exception
        MessageBox.Show("error :: " & e.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Function LocalReportCreateStreamCallback(ByVal name As String, ByVal extension As String, ByVal encoding As Encoding, ByVal mimeType As String, ByVal willSeek As Boolean) As Stream
    Dim stream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream()
    m_pages.Add(stream)
    Return stream
End Function

Private Function CreateEMFDeviceInfo(PageHeight As Integer, PageWidth as Integer) As String
    Dim paperSize As PaperSize = m_pageSettings.PaperSize
    Dim margins As Margins = m_pageSettings.Margins
    Return String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "<DeviceInfo><OutputFormat>emf</OutputFormat>
                                                        <StartPage>0</StartPage>
                                                        <EndPage>0</EndPage>
                                                        <MarginTop>{0}</MarginTop>
                                                        <MarginLeft>{1}</MarginLeft>
                                                        <MarginRight>{2}</MarginRight>
                                                        <MarginBottom>{3}</MarginBottom>
                                                        <PageHeight>" & PageHeight & "</PageHeight>
                                                        <PageWidth>" & PageWidth & "</PageWidth>
                                                        </DeviceInfo>", ToInches(margins.Top),
                                                        ToInches(margins.Left), ToInches(margins.Right),
                                                        ToInches(margins.Bottom), ToInches(paperSize.Height),
                                                        ToInches(paperSize.Width))


End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply, but isn't it still hardcoded into the class itself?

Comment: Then abstract it one level farther, or make make the variables public